# Numerical calculations using mpmath and numpy in python get different results?

Tags: python, numpy, mpmath

I first did a numerical calculation with numpy and the result was correct, but due to insufficient precision, it could lead to errors. So I used mpmath for the calculation instead, but I found that the result was different.

## The code with numpy:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from sympy import Poly
from functools import lru_cache

y, omega = sy.symbols('y omega')

def lambda0_f(y):
    return 2 * y * (1 - 1j * omega) / (1 - y**2)

def s0_f(y):
    return (1 - 2 * 1j * omega - 2 * omega**2) / (2 * (1 - y**2))

y0_val = 0.4
num_val = 3

lambda0_series = sy.series(lambda0_f(y), y, y0_val, num_val+1).removeO()
s0_series = sy.series(s0_f(y), y, y0_val, num_val+1).removeO()

def c0i(i0):
    if i0 == 0:
        return lambda0_f(y0_val)
    else:
        return lambda0_series.coeff((y-y0_val)**i0) 

def d0i(i0):
    if i0 == 0:
        return s0_f(y0_val)
    else:
        return s0_series.coeff((y-y0_val)**i0)
  
c0i_coeffs = [Poly(c0i(i), omega).all_coeffs() for i in range(num_val+1)]
d0i_coeffs = [Poly(d0i(i), omega).all_coeffs() for i in range(num_val+1)]

c0i_coeffs_np = [np.array(coef, dtype=np.complex128) for coef in c0i_coeffs]
d0i_coeffs_np = [np.array(coef, dtype=np.complex128) for coef in d0i_coeffs]

def convolve_polys(poly1, poly2):
    return np.convolve(poly1, poly2)

def poly_add(poly1, poly2):
    len_diff = len(poly1) - len(poly2)
    if len_diff > 0:
        poly2 = np.pad(poly2, (len_diff, 0), mode='constant')
    elif len_diff < 0:
        poly1 = np.pad(poly1, (-len_diff, 0), mode='constant')
    return poly1 + poly2

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0, num, c0_coeffs, d0_coeffs):
    if num == 0:
        return c0_coeffs[i0], d0_coeffs[i0]

    c_result = np.zeros(num, dtype=np.complex128)
    d_result = np.zeros(num, dtype=np.complex128)

    for k in range(i0 + 1):
        c_result, d_result=poly_add(c_result, convolve_polys(np.array(c0_coeffs[k]), np.array(compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 - k, num - 1, tuple(map(tuple, c0_coeffs)), tuple(map(tuple, d0_coeffs)))[0]))),poly_add(d_result, convolve_polys(np.array(d0_coeffs[k]), np.array(compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 - k, num - 1, tuple(map(tuple, c0_coeffs)), tuple(map(tuple, d0_coeffs)))[0])))

    if i0 + 1 <= num_val:
        c_result, d_result=poly_add(c_result, poly_add((i0 + 1) * np.array(compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 + 1, num - 1, tuple(map(tuple, c0_coeffs)), tuple(map(tuple, d0_coeffs)))[0]), np.array(compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0, num - 1, tuple(map(tuple, c0_coeffs)), tuple(map(tuple, d0_coeffs)))[1]))),poly_add(d_result, (i0 + 1) * np.array(compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 + 1, num - 1, tuple(map(tuple, c0_coeffs)), tuple(map(tuple, d0_coeffs)))[1]))


    return tuple(c_result), tuple(d_result)

cni_coeffs, dni_coeffs = compute_cni_dni_coeffs(0, num_val, tuple(map(tuple, c0i_coeffs_np)), tuple(map(tuple, d0i_coeffs_np)))

cni_coeffs, dni_coeffs = compute_cni_dni_coeffs(0, num_val, tuple(map(tuple, c0i_coeffs_np)), tuple(map(tuple, d0i_coeffs_np)))

print("cni_coeffs:", cni_coeffs)
print("dni_coeffs:", dni_coeffs)
```

## The code with mpmath:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import mpmath
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp, mpc
import sympy as sy
from sympy import symbols, Poly

ndps=20
mp.dps = ndps 

y, rh, r2, omega, l ,M,Q= sy.symbols('y r_h r_2 omega ell M Q')

def lambda0_f(y):
    return 2 * y * (1 - 1j * omega) / (1 - y**2 + 1e-15)


def s0_f(y):
    return (1 - 2 * 1j * omega - 2 * omega**2) / (2 * (1 - y**2 + 1e-15))

y0_val = 0.4
num_val =3

lambda0_series = sy.series(lambda0_f(y), y, y0_val, num_val+1).removeO()
s0_series = sy.series(s0_f(y), y, y0_val, num_val+1).removeO()

def c0i(i0):
    if i0 == 0:
        return lambda0_f(y0_val)
    else:
        return lambda0_series.coeff((y-y0_val)**i0) 


def d0i(i0):
    if i0 == 0:
        return s0_f(y0_val)
    else:
        return s0_series.coeff((y-y0_val)**i0)

c0i_coeffs = [Poly(c0i(i),omega).all_coeffs() for i in range(num_val+1)]
d0i_coeffs = [Poly(d0i(i),omega).all_coeffs() for i in range(num_val+1)]

c0i_coeffs_np = [np.array(coef, dtype=np.complex128) for coef in c0i_coeffs]
d0i_coeffs_np = [np.array(coef, dtype=np.complex128) for coef in d0i_coeffs]


def numpy_to_mpmath(x):
    return [[mpc(np.real(y),np.imag(y)) for y in z ] for z in x ]

lambda_coes_mpmath = [[mpc(np.real(y),np.imag(y)) for y in z ] for z in c0i_coeffs_np ]
s_coes_mpmath = [[mpc(np.real(y),np.imag(y)) for y in z ] for z in d0i_coeffs_np ]

def poly_add(poly1, poly2):
    if len(poly2) > len(poly1):
        poly1, poly2 = poly2, poly1
    result = [mpc(0) for _ in range(len(poly1))]
    for i in range(len(poly2)):
        result[i] = poly1[i] + poly2[i]
    for i in range(len(poly2), len(poly1)):
        result[i] = poly1[i]
    return result

def convolve_polys(p1, p2):
    result_length = len(p1) + len(p2) - 1
    result = [mpc(0) for _ in range(result_length)]
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        for j in range(len(p2)):
            result[i + j] += p1[i] * p2[j]
    return result

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0, num, c0_coeffs, d0_coeffs):
    if num == 0:
        return c0_coeffs[i0], d0_coeffs[i0]

    c_result = [mpc(0) for _ in range(num)]
    d_result = [mpc(0) for _ in range(num)]

    for k in range(i0 + 1):
        c_k, d_k = compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 - k, num - 1, c0_coeffs, d0_coeffs)
        c_result,d_result = poly_add(c_result, convolve_polys(c0_coeffs[k], c_k)),poly_add(d_result, convolve_polys(d0_coeffs[k], c_k))
    if i0 + 1 <= num_val:
        c_next, d_next = compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0 + 1, num - 1, c0_coeffs, d0_coeffs)
        _,d_c0=compute_cni_dni_coeffs(i0, num - 1, c0_coeffs, d0_coeffs)
        c_result = poly_add(c_result, poly_add(convolve_polys(c_next, [mpc(i0 + 1,0)]), d_c0))
        d_result = poly_add(d_result, convolve_polys(d_next, [mpc(i0 + 1,0)]))

    return c_result, d_result

cni_coeffs, dni_coeffs = compute_cni_dni_coeffs(0, num_val, tuple(map(tuple, lambda_coes_mpmath)), tuple(map(tuple, s_coes_mpmath)))
```

Please help me get the right results from mpmath, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question would benefit from a simplified example that reproduces the issue. As is, we do not know what type of calculation you are trying to perform nor what the expected answer is. In the process of writing a short example, you may be able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: what are the results?

Comment: The results should be:
cni_coeffs: ((5.4793270293756215+0j), 54.79327029375621j, (-194.81337508548393+0j), -289.1509967554672j, (151.49696499915157+0j))
dni_coeffs: (-3.727870588900716j, (37.278705889007156+0j), 133.68915215368082j, (-208.5679320859107+0j), -142.65532365629548j, (46.75906643836673+0j))

Comment: But what are they?  Don't expect us to run your code - unless the issue sounds very interesting.

Comment: Sorry for that. The results in numpy are shown above. The results in mpmath are: cni_coeffs: [-74.4320782   -8.90832523j -47.93527388-128.9971771j
  53.3117631  -85.26539868j  28.42179956 -11.18682545j
   2.79670636  +0.j        ]
dni_coeffs: [  2.6994925 +42.67769088j -80.59913308+47.43393956j
 -68.45141685-52.12591461j   9.44822373-44.73444707j
  11.18361177 -5.94531085j   1.18906217 +0.j ] (The output is converted to numpy format)